# Opencart, product description in different languages and change description automatically with respect to selected language by user

Tags: opencart

All

It is very urgent that i want to support multi language in my opencart. So i want to set translated product description in different language.

Finally, when an user  select a language from home page then all products description will be shown on the selected language.

e.g:
by default language: english, product Description:English.
if user selects french language ,then product Description: in french language.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you added the second language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is basic functionality of the opencart. You need to install language extension and add new languages to opencart. Once you add new languages you will be able to set your product descriptions to these new languages. There rest will work as you describe

Here is the tutorial I found. 
http://www.tmdhosting.com/tutorials/opencart/opencart-add-language.html

Language extensions can be found on opencart site

Comment: wow, got, thank you very much. really it is simple as you described.